# Cannot use a variable from 1 function into another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use lat and lng from the getLocation() function in my marker but it wont work.

I added the alert because if that one works everything will.

```
I tried var lat = ...
I tried world.lat = ...
```

Something with return values

```
function getLocation() {
var onSuccess = function (position) {
    console.log('Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '\n' +
        'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude + '\n' +
        'Altitude: ' + position.coords.altitude + '\n' +
        'Accuracy: ' + position.coords.accuracy + '\n' +
        'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy + '\n' +
        'Heading: ' + position.coords.heading + '\n' +
        'Speed: ' + position.coords.speed + '\n' +
        'Timestamp: ' + position.timestamp + '\n');

    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    $('.locationLatitude').text(lat);
    lng = position.coords.longitude;
    $('.locationLongitude').text(lng);
    console.log(`latitude: ${lat} longitude: ${lng}`);
};

function onError(error) {
    console.log('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
        'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    alert(`code: ${error.code}
    message: ${error.message}
    Please turn on your GPS`);
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}
alert(lat, lng);
function meOnMap() {
    marker2 = L.marker([lat, lng]).addTo(map).bindPopup('Your Location').openPopup();
}
```

I expected that the lat and lng values returns their values from in the other function, but they don't.

Comment: Did you try to set the lat and lng as global variables?

Comment: My question is how do I get them to be global variables?

Comment: avoiding using global var as much as possible is better but it you can then just equate the global var to new value

Comment: I think the reason the `lat` and `lng` does not have a value is that the `getLocation()` hasn't been executed yet.

Comment: You order a pizza via their webpage. As soon as hit enter you try to eat the pizza. That is what you are doing. The pizza has not been made and delivered yet. Asynchronous 101

Comment: getLocation();
alert(lat, lng);
and I still get Uncaught ReferenceError: lat is not defined

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want `lat` and `lng` to be in scope when referenced in your `meOnMap` function. The comments are on the right track, you could declare them as global variables. To do that, just put `var lat, lng;` at the top of your file.

Or you could add some paramaters to your `meOnMap` function declaration and call it inside your success callback function, after it does all the processing stuff:

```
function meOnMap(lat, lng) {
    marker2 = L.marker([lat, lng]).addTo(map).bindPopup('Your Location').openPopup();
}
var onSuccess = function (position) {
    ...
    meOnMap(lat,lng);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call your `getLocation` function.

```
.... 
getLocation();
alert(lat, lng);
```

Comment: I still get: Uncaught ReferenceError: lat is not defined